# How do I custom the 24 hour start hour and finish hour for line plot? (for example, start at 7:30)

Tags: r

I have a 24 hour data starting from 7:30 today (for example), until 7:30 the next day, because I didn't link the date to the line plot, R sorts the hour starting from 00:00 despite the data starting at 7:30, I am a beginner in R, and I don't know where to begin to even solve this problem, should I try linking the date also to the X axis, or is there a better solution?

My time function somehow didn't work either, it used to work when I was plotting data for 15 minute increments.

```
library(chron)
d <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header = T)
t <- times(d$Time)
plot(t,d$MCO2, type="l")
```

Graph created from the 24 hour data I have :

[image: Graph created from the 24 hour data I have]

Graph created from a 15 minute data using the same code :

[image: Graph created from a 15 minute data using the same code]

I wanted the outcome to be from `7:30` to `7:30` the next day, but it showed now a decimal number from `0.0` to `1`

Here is the link to the data, just in case:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsg437gu00e5t08/Data%20210519.csv?dl=0

Comment: Could you provide data to make a reproducible example please

Comment: @rg255 https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsg437gu00e5t08/Data%20210519.csv?dl=0

Comment: Please see the help pages RE providing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is actually about combining a date column and a time column to create a timestamp containing date AND time. Note that I suggest to process everything as if we are in GMT timezone. You can pick whatever timezone you want, then stick to it.

```
# use ggplot
library(ggplot2)
# assume everything happens in GMT timezone
Sys.setenv( TZ = "GMT" )

# replicating the data: a measurement result sampled at 1 sec interval
t <- seq(start, end, by = "1 sec")
Time24 <- trimws(strftime(t, format = "%k:%M:%OS", tz="GMT"))
Date <- strftime(t, format = "%d/%m/%Y", tz="GMT")
head(Time24)
head(Date)
d <- data.frame(Date, Time24)
# this is just a random data of temperature
d$temp <- rnorm(length(d$Date),mean=25,sd=5)
head(d)
# the resulting data is as follows
#        Date  Time24     temp
#1 22/05/2019 0:00:00 22.67185
#2 22/05/2019 0:00:01 19.91123
#3 22/05/2019 0:00:02 19.57393
#4 22/05/2019 0:00:03 15.37280
#5 22/05/2019 0:00:04 31.76683
#6 22/05/2019 0:00:05 26.75153

# this is the answer to the question
# which is combining the the date and the time column of the data
# note we still assume that this happens in GMT
t <- as.POSIXct(paste(d$Date,d$Time24,sep=" "), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS", tz="GMT")

# print the data into a plot
png(filename = "test.png", width = 800, height = 600, units = "px", pointsize = 22 )
ggplot(d,aes(x=t,y=temp)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hour",
                   date_labels = "%H:%M\n%d-%b")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function times does not include information about the day. This is a problem since your data spans two days.

The data type you use should be able to include information about the day. Posix is this data type. Also, since Posix is the go-to date-time object in R it is much easier to plot.

Before plotting the data, the time column should have the correct difference in days. When just transforming the column with as.POSIXct, the times of day 2 are read as if it is from day 1. This is why we have to add 24 hours to the correct entries.

After that, it is just a matter of plotting. I added an example of the package of ggplot2 since I prefer these plots.

You might notice that using as.POSIXct will add an incorrect date to your time information. Don't bother about this, you use this date just as a dummy date. You don't use this date itself, you just use it to be able to work with the difference in days.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Read in your data set    
d <- read.csv(file="Data 210519.csv", header = T)

# Read column into R date-time object
t <- as.POSIXct(d$Time24, format = "%H:%M:%OS")

# Add 24 hours to time the time on day 2.
startOfDayTwo <- as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%OS")
endOfDayTwo <- as.POSIXct("07:35:00", format = "%H:%M:%OS")
t[t >= startOfDayTwo & t <= endOfDayTwo] <- t[t >= startOfDayTwo & t <= endOfDayTwo] + 24*60*60

plot(t,d$MCO2, type="l")

# arguably a nicer plot
ggplot(d,aes(x=t,y=MCO2)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hour",
                   date_labels = "%I:%M %p")
```

[image: The picture that ggplot produces]